# member usage in thread blocks ui

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, block

i have a class containing a member of type ClassA. the ClassA class provides a time expensive method DoWork(). I want to call this method in a thread. Let's assume the MainClass class is the view model of a wpf application and the application has a button. When the button is clicked the Call_DoWork() method is called. This is my code:

```cs
public class MainClass {
    private classA _classA;

    public MainClass() {
        _classA = new ClassA();
    }

    public void Call_DoWork() {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => { _classA.DoWork(); });
        t.Start();
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    public void DoWork() {
        // Do some time consuming things ...
    }
}
```

When i run the application and click the button the gui is blocked by the thread. This is because the thread uses the _classA member. If the _classA member is instanziated in the thread the gui is not blocked and everything is fine.

My question: is there another way to use the _classA member in the thread without blocking the gui?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I have to use VS2010 and the target framework is .NET 3.5.

Comment: I would advise using [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) in this scenario.

Comment: Oh, i forgot to say that i have to use VS2010 and .Net 3.5....

Comment: _"This is because the thread uses the _classA member"_ - I don't think so. You probably simplified the code too much.

Comment: Here's an [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/634146/Background-Thread-Let-me-count-the-ways) that lists quite a few different ways to execute code in a background thread. Keep in mind, the Task and Parallel operations won't apply since you're on .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.90).aspx)?

It's easy to use, and the nice thing about it is that `ProgressChanged` method is executing on the main UI thread of WPF application, so you can use it to update UI during background execution.